# Why is Thelma's mother in a wheelchair?

Tags: plot-explanation, thelma

In the film [Thelma](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6304046/), some parts show Thelma aged 6, others show Thelma starting university.  Throughout the film, the cause of several events become clear during the course of the film:

> - Thelma's sister has disappeared and died;
>  - Thelma's grandfather has vanished without a trace;
>  - Anja disappears.
>
>
>  All due to Thelma's powers or her grandmother's.

The film also shows that in Thelma's youth, her mother was walking around normally, but later in life, her mother is in a wheelchair.

Does the film explain anywhere how this happened?

> Was it Thelma?
>  Was it Thelma's grandmother?

I may have missed it.

Comment: ["We are also left to ponder why Thelma’s mother ended up in a wheelchair."](http://www.justaplatform.com/thelma-film-review/)